# Build a truncated tower with numbers from 1 to 9 without repeating

Tags: equation-solving, syntax

consider the image subject to the following conditions appearing in my code, I find not the appropriate numbers

[image]

```
Reduce[a + b == f, b + c == g, c + d == h, 
d + e == i, {1 <= a <= 9, 1 <= b <= 9, 1 <= c <= 9, 1 <= d <= 9, 
  1 <= e <= 9, 1 <= f <= 9, 1 <= g <= 9, 1 <= h <= 9, 
  1 <= i <= 9}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Integers]
```

**not find results for the problem**

edit
*if wrong code, I want the numbers are not repeated*

Answer (score 3):

```
eqns = {a + b == f, b + c == g, c + d == h, d + e == i};

vars = Variables[Level[eqns, {-1}]]

(*  {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}  *)
```

The constraints can be slightly tightened from `1 <= vars[[i]] <= 9` since the largest possible number in the bottom row is 8 (i.e., 9 - 1) and the smallest possible number in the top row is 3 (i.e., 1 + 2).

```
cons = {1 <= a <= 8, 1 <= b <= 8, 1 <= c <= 8, 1 <= d <= 8, 1 <= e <= 8, 
   3 <= f <= 9, 3 <= g <= 9, 3 <= h <= 9, 3 <= i <= 9};
```

`Select` is used to require that all nine digits are used, i.e., once each.

```
soln = Select[
  Solve[{eqns, cons} // Flatten, vars, Integers],
  Union[vars /. #] === Range[9] &]

(*  {{a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 5, f -> 4, g -> 9, h -> 8, 
  i -> 7}, {a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 6, e -> 2, f -> 5, g -> 7, h -> 9, 
  i -> 8}, {a -> 2, b -> 6, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 1, f -> 8, g -> 9, h -> 7, 
  i -> 5}, {a -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 6, d -> 3, e -> 1, f -> 7, g -> 8, h -> 9, 
  i -> 4}, {a -> 5, b -> 4, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 7, f -> 9, g -> 6, h -> 3, 
  i -> 8}, {a -> 7, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 8, g -> 3, h -> 6, 
  i -> 9}}  *)
```

The number of solutions are

```
Length[soln]

(*  6  *)
```

Verifying that the solutions satisfy the eqns and constraints

```
And @@ Flatten[{eqns, cons} /. soln]

(*  True  *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a syntax error and should be,

```
Reduce[{a + b == f, b + c == g, c + d == h, d + e == i, 0 <= a <= 9, 
    0 <= b <= 9, 0 <= c <= 9, 0 <= d <= 9, 0 <= e <= 9, 0 <= f <= 9, 
    0 <= g <= 9, 0 <= h <= 9, 0 <= i <= 9}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, 
    i}, Integers]
```

However, with this correction the code produces 5916 possible answers.  Here is a fast way to `Select` the correct ones.

```
possibilities = Reduce[{a + b == f, b + c == g, c + d == h, d + e == i, 
    1 <= a <= 9, 1 <= b <= 9, 1 <= c <= 9, 1 <= d <= 9, 1 <= e <= 9, 1 <= f <= 9,
    1 <= g <= 9, 1 <= h <= 9, 1 <= i <= 9}, {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, Integers] 
    /. Or -> List /. And -> List /. Equal -> Rule;
```

the first of which is

```
(* {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> 1, e -> 1, f -> 2, g -> 2, h -> 2, i -> 2} *)
```

The selection criteria are

```
criteria = (Sort[#] & /@ Permutations[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i}, {2}] // Union) /. 
    List[z1_, z2_] -> z1 != z2 /. List -> And
(* a != b && a != c && a != d && a != e && a != f && a != g && a != h && 
   a != i && b != c && b != d && b != e && b != f && b != g && b != h &&
   b != i && c != d && c != e && c != f && c != g && c != h && c != i &&
   d != e && d != f && d != g && d != h && d != i && e != f && e != g &&
   e != h && e != i && f != g && f != h && f != i && g != h && g != i &&
   h != i *)
```

Finally,

```
Select[possibilities, (criteria /. #) &]
(* {{a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 5, f -> 4, g -> 9, h -> 8, i -> 7}, 
    {a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 6, e -> 2, f -> 5, g -> 7, h -> 9, i -> 8}, 
    {a -> 2, b -> 6, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 1, f -> 8, g -> 9, h -> 7, i -> 5}, 
    {a -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 6, d -> 3, e -> 1, f -> 7, g -> 8, h -> 9, i -> 4}, 
    {a -> 5, b -> 4, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 7, f -> 9, g -> 6, h -> 3, i -> 8}, 
    {a -> 7, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 8, g -> 3, h -> 6, i -> 9}} *)
```

Total run-time, measured by `AbsoluteTiming`, is less than a second.

Incidentally, if {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i} is a solution, then {e, d, c, b, a, i, h, g, f} is an equivalent solution, obtained by reversing the order of the numbers on both levels of the figure in the question.  On this basis, there are only three inequivalent solutions.

Comment: if wrong code, I want the numbers are not repeated

Comment: And also between 1 and 9, not 0 and 9, right?

Comment: yes....I did not see it

Comment: thaks , I served much your analysis

Answer (score 2):

```
eqs = {a + b == f, b + c == g, c + d == h, d + e == i};
constraints = 1 <= # <= 9 & /@ {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
nums = List@ToRules@Reduce[eqs~Join~constraints, Integers];
sols = GroupBy[nums, Range[9] == Sort[Values@#] &][True]
And @@ eqs /. # & /@ sols
(* {{a -> 1, b -> 3, c -> 6, d -> 2, e -> 5, f -> 4, g -> 9, h -> 8, i -> 7},
    {a -> 1, b -> 4, c -> 3, d -> 6, e -> 2, f -> 5, g -> 7, h -> 9, i -> 8},
    {a -> 2, b -> 6, c -> 3, d -> 4, e -> 1, f -> 8, g -> 9, h -> 7, i -> 5},
    {a -> 5, b -> 2, c -> 6, d -> 3, e -> 1, f -> 7, g -> 8, h -> 9, i -> 4},
    {a -> 5, b -> 4, c -> 2, d -> 1, e -> 7, f -> 9, g -> 6, h -> 3, i -> 8},
    {a -> 7, b -> 1, c -> 2, d -> 4, e -> 5, f -> 8, g -> 3, h -> 6, i -> 9}} *)
(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

I have separated out the list of equations from the list of constraints for clarity, but they are the same as in the OPost. We use `Reduce` to get all of the solutions to this set of equations in the integers, and `ToRules` transforms the output of `Reduce`, which is in the form of logical statements involving `&&`s and `||`s, into a list of replacement rules, which is the standard output for `Solve`.

The real work is done by `GroupBy`, which groups the elements in the list `num` of solutions according to the value that the function in the second argument of `GroupBy` evaluates to. The function `Range[9] == Sort[Values@#] &` tests whether the values in a particular solution are all different or not by checking to see whether all the numbers between `1` and `9` are in the list. The function evaluates to `True` it is such a solution and `False` if it is not.

`GroupBy` returns an `Association`, and we can call the elements in the association related to the `Key` `True` with `[True]`. This returns the solutions that we want. Finally, we test again to make sure that we are actually returning solutions in the final line.

Comment: you kindly explain a little code thanks

Comment: thanks, I served much your approach to the problem

Answer (score 2):

A completely different take on a solution:

```
answers = Block[{i, j = Join @@ Permutations /@ Subsets[Range@9, {5}]},
  Join[#, Tr /@ Partition[#, 2, 1]] & /@ 
   Select[j, (Intersection[i = Tr /@ Partition[#, 2, 1], #] == {} && 
       Max[i] <= 9 && Length@Union@i == 4) &]]
```

Comment: you kindly explain a little code thanks